# android Reactive error: IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 180 path $.body

Tags: android, system.reactive, retrofit

I'm trying to create multiples calls with reactive and then join that in a object with a response, if i used it this way i get this error retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 180 path $.body
if i uncomment the line inside the function getAccountCurrentBalance(that only get the data hardcoded and not from the API) it's works!. I don´t see the problem :( please some help

```
    public Observable<Account> getAccounts(ArrayList<Account> accounts, String currency) {
                ArrayList<Observable<Account>> accountObservables = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Account account : accounts) {
                    // Create a form
                    final Form<AccountDetailForm> form = new Form<>();
                    AccountDetailForm accountDetailForm = new AccountDetailForm(
                            account.getIban(), currency);
                    form.setBody(accountDetailForm);

                    // Get all account info
                    Observable<Account> accountInfoObservable = Observable.just(account);

                    accountObservables.add(
                            accountInfoObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Account, Observable<Account>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Observable<Account> call(final Account account) {
                                    return Observable.combineLatest(getAccountCurrentBalance(form),
                                            getAccountsCards(form),
                                            new Func2<String, ArrayList<Card>, Account>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public Account call(String currentBalance,
                                                        ArrayList<Card> cards) {
                                                    account.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance);
                                                    account.setCards(cards);
                                                    return account;
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            }));

                }
                // finally convert detail of observables to a single observable
                return Observable.merge(accountObservables);
            }


            public Observable<String> getAccountCurrentBalance(Form<AccountDetailForm> form) {
//return Observable.just("213123");
                return mGateway.getAccountCurrentBalance(form));
            }

        private Observable<ArrayList<Card>> getAccountsCards(Form<AccountDetailForm> form) {
                return mGateway.getAccountCards(form)
                        .filter(new Func1<ArrayList<Card>, Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public Boolean call(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
                                if (cards.size() == 0) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Comment: i think is something about the time of response of the API but i can't find a solution.

Comment: if i call the endpoints individually that parse works